# Querying for an email address with a plus (+) sign with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I'm adapting a Powershell script I have that queries for and creates EXO contacts and users based on a list of names and email addresses from AzureAD to MS Graph.

In my old script I could query for an email address with Get-EXORecipient and Get-AzureADUser.
In the new world I'm using Get-MgUser and Get-MgContact.

For the most part this has worked fine but I've now hit a wrinkle where I have multiple different contacts that have the same base email address using plus addressing to differentiate (so, user+a@foo.com, user+b@foo.com, user+c@foo.com, etc.).

My old script handled this fine. But it appears the MS Graph cmdlets interpret the + as a special character and fail to return results, which breaks my script.

Is there an easy way to escape or handle this case that doesn't require me to do input validation every time? I was hoping this would continue to be just a straight string comparison.

At a basic level, I'm just trying to do this:

```
 Get-MgContact -consistencylevel eventual -Search 'mail:foo@foo.com'
```

and either get a result or not.

If the Contact has an email address with a plus in it, this barfs.

`Get-MgContact -consistencylevel eventual -Search 'mail:foo+a@foo.com'`
returns no results even if this Contact email address exists.

I can do a partial query and this works, except I have multiple contacts of different people who share the same base email address (this is a family and they're using the + for their kids).

So I can do `Get-MgContact -consistencylevel eventual -Search 'mail:foo'` and get all corresponding resuts, but once I add the + I get nothing. I've tried this with both single quotes and double quotes with no difference.

This all worked fine with the old cmdlets, but I'm stuck figuring out how to handle this scenario?

Comment: According to [RFC 3696](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3696#section-3) the plus sign is *just* a valid character. `user+a@foo.com` and `user+b@foo.com` do not have to be the same mailbox `user@foo.com`. It depends on the e-mail provider. Most probably, your search filter does not work with a plus sign because it either does not properly escape characters that it should escape (`+` may be a meta character in a search string) or it uses a wrong regex for e-mail addresses, as there are plenty of them on the internet. I recommend to file a bug report.

Comment: What happens with `... -Search "mail:'foo+a@foo.com'"`?

Comment: I would try the similar as @stackprotector suggested `-Search '"mail:foo+a@foo.com"'` Search is using KQL language and I'm afraid that KQL interprets `+` as `AND` operator. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference#boolean-operators

Comment: @stackprotector this isn't about the email address itself, rather how Get-MgContact seems to barf on plus-encoded email addressing when searching.

To answer your question on the enclosed double/single quote: 
`-Search "mail:'foo+a@foo.com'"` this also fails to return results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and below is the result**

The issue you are facing is due to the plus sign (+) is a special character in **Microsoft Graph** query language, and it is used to represent a space in a search query.

If I try to fetch user contact details using `-Search`, I get the below error.

```
Get-MgContact -consistencylevel eventual -Search "Theja+a@xxxxxxxxx.OnMicrosoft.com"
```

**Error**

[image]

To resolve the issue, you can use the **-replace** operator to replace the plus sign with the **URL** encoded version **"%2B"**.

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Identity.DirectoryManagement -Force
Update-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Identity.DirectoryManagement -Force

Connect-MgGraph –Scopes "Application.ReadWrite.All","DeviceManagementApps.Read.All", "Directory.AccessAsUser.All","Directory.ReadWrite.All"

$email = 'Theja+a@M365x77030329.OnMicrosoft.com'
$urlEncodedEmail = $email -replace '\+','%2B'
$searchQuery = "mail:$urlEncodedEmail"

$Result= Get-MgContact -consistencylevel eventual -Search $searchQuery
$Result
```

**Output**

[image]

Reference:  MS Doc [Get-MgContact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/get-mgcontact?view=graph-powershell-1.0)

Comment: So what's interesting with your example here is that your format is incorrect because you didn't specify the property value to search for (mail:). I noticed because I didn't get the format error when I did this with a + sign but trying your version literally did create the same error result.

I had a screenshot but can't figure out how to add it here (sorry, first time poster). I'm trying the escaping suggestion now.

Comment: You would think that they'd recognize that to require escaping a valid email address character within the query string itself (especially without erroring) would be a recipe for confusion. So I need to attempt escaping on every string in advance.